# Disable full page scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I am working on a piece of code where there are 6 sections and full-page scrolling is implemented in the view. So when we are on section 4 and we scroll down, we scroll down to section 5 completely.
But I want to disable this full-page scrolling for one of the sections, say section 2 (i.e. when the user is on section 2 and they scroll down, the normal scrolling behavior should occur rather than full-page scrolling)

I am stuck on this problem for a while, Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?
Should I use fullpage(jquery) functionality?

Comment: @Spectric The code is lot so its not possible me to share here. I will again try to explain you what is the issue. So there is a HTML page with 6 sections and full page scrolling functionality is implemented in the view. So if I am on section 3 and scrolldown a little, I will be directly be sent to section 4. But I want to disable this scrolling and have normal scrolling for section 5 but I am not able to achieve that

Comment: Your full page scrolling should be implemented by adding an event listener onscroll and prevent Default. And scroll to a desired XY... Improve your event listener to skip preventDefault only when you are in 5th section.. if you are using any library to do your scroll.. investigate the options in that library

Answer (score 0):

maybe I don't understand your problem, but you want to hide the browser scrollbar?

```
        html, body {
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
```

otherwise perhaps pictures would be quite helpful or an example

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't want this. Please read my comment which I have posted in the question to understand my question further

Comment: okay maybe i understand now.
I think you can only fix this problem by knowing which page you are on and explicitly preventing full page scrolling from a certain function.

Comment: I know how to figure out when I reach that section but how can i prevent the full page scrolling.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help if I can't see how you implemented full page scrolling.

Are you using an EventListener, wheel maybe?

Comment: I think by removing the class which is causing the scroll from the div/section will solve your problem..